# How to get the time python started executing a code and add it as a column in your text file

Tags: python, csv, file, datetime

I want to know the exact time python started running my code. I would like to extract this time in DMY-HMS and add it as a new column in my text files (I prefer it to be added on the left).

[My text file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mfXg.png) and after I ran the code for example on the first of July on 12:00 o' clock : [I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQB67.png)

This is my current code, but I got stuck. Please note that I need to do this for multiple files so that is why placed my code in a loop. I would really appreciate your help all!

```
import os, os.path
import time

source = r'c:\data\ARS\Desktop\Location'

date_time = (timeit.timeit)) ?#<=== this has to be the exact time the code has run in DMY-HMS.


for file in os.walk(source):
# Open the input_file in read mode and output_file in write mode
    with open (file, 'rt')  as in_put, open(file, 'rt') as out_put:
#Create a csv.reader object from the input file object        
        csv_reader = csv.reader(in_put)
#Create a csv.writer object from the output file object
        csv_writer = csv.writer(out_put)
#Append the default text in the row / list        
        for row in csv_reader:
            row.append(date_time)
#Add the updated row / list to the output file            
            csv_writer.writrow(row)
```

Comment: why are you writing the output to a column there is no relation between the time and other columns?

Comment: @komatiraju032 Well, my ultimate goal is to write this file into a MySQL table so I can directly see when the code was run.

Comment: for example your table has 5 rows and you run your program 50 times if you follow this approach there is 45 unnecessary rows with single column time

Comment: @komatiraju032 Well im fine to say im new to Python and im still learning, it would be great if you came up with a sort of solution.

Comment: from where you adding other columns data? you can add the time there only

Comment: What about `datetime.now()`? E.g. `datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat()` to get a string including UTC offset

Comment: @komatiraju032 What do you mean?

Comment: @MrFuppes you mean I need to insert your code in date_time?

Comment: you would also have to `from datetime import datetime`, then you could use `date_time = datetime.now().astimezone().isoformat()`.

Comment: @MrFuppes aha thats a good one. But it prints out +02:00 at the end , I dont need that. How do I remove that?

Comment: just `datetime.now().isoformat()` then...

Comment: @MrFuppes, can I mark your reaction as an answer.

Comment: No worries, I'm glad if I could help you. No need for an extra answer here.